# Какой символ прописать в имени файла чтобы он при сортировке был первым?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, windows, mac

Доброго времени суток!
У меня возникла проблема с сортировками имен файлов, если первым в имени файла идет символ.
Пример:

```
_trash
aName
bName
cName
```

В примере выше всё правильно — так сортируют даже винда и мак. Но, если с алфавитом все понятно и мы знаем как назвать файл, чтоб тот был первым в отсортированном списке, то как быть с символьным названием файла? У символов есть какой-то порядок?

Я пробовал несколько вариантов, добавляя разные символы в название, но сортировка просто не происходила и имена оставались на тех же местах.
Пример:

```
!trash
&trash
_trash
aName
bName
cName
```

Обратная сортировка:

```
aName
bName
cName
!trash
&trash
_trash
```

**Как видите, имена с символом вначале просто не сортируются**.

Comment: Вам внизу про локализацию ответили.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю сортировка выполняется по коду `ASCII` символов

В строке вы можете узнать код символа при помощи метода `charCodeAt`

Посмотрите пример:

```js
const str_1 = '!target'
const str_2 = '&target'
const str_3 = '_target'

const str_4 = 'aName'
const str_5 = 'bName'
const str_6 = 'cName'

console.log(str_1.charCodeAt(0))
console.log(str_2.charCodeAt(0))
console.log(str_3.charCodeAt(0))

console.log(str_4.charCodeAt(0))
console.log(str_5.charCodeAt(0))
console.log(str_6.charCodeAt(0))
```

Comment: Но если код символа восклицательного знака имеет меньшее значение чем символ нижнего подчеркивания, почему сортировка не происходит? Попробуйте у себя на ПК создать три файла (_target, &target и !target), и попробуйте их отсортировать по имени прямо в операционке. Отсортированы они не будут почему-то...

Comment: @Saniate Сортируются. Если имелось ввиду просто создать 3 файла, без программирования, и сортировать их по имени

Comment: @Saniate Вы пробовали закрыть и открыть папку? Или нажать "обновить" ?

Answer (score 0):

Это фокусы локализации.

Установите `LC_ALL=C` и смотрите на ожидаемый (в порядке ascii кодов) вывод:

```
avp@avp-desktop:/tmp/t$ cat 2
&
c
a
_
b
!
avp@avp-desktop:/tmp/t$ ls | cat
2
aFile
bFile
cFile
_file
!file
&file
avp@avp-desktop:/tmp/t$ sort 2
_
!
&
a
b
c
avp@avp-desktop:/tmp/t$ 
avp@avp-desktop:/tmp/t$ 
avp@avp-desktop:/tmp/t$ LC_ALL=C sort 2
!
&
_
a
b
c
avp@avp-desktop:/tmp/t$ LC_ALL=C ls |cat
!file
&file
2
_file
aFile
bFile
cFile
avp@avp-desktop:/tmp/t$ uname -a; cat /etc/issue
Linux avp-desktop 5.4.0-122-generic #138~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 14:14:03 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia \n \l

avp@avp-desktop:/tmp/t$
```

Comment: Какие ascii коды, если локализация, например, UTF8?

Comment: @0andriy, кодировка ascii в utf-8 (именно такие символы мы видим в примере вопроса и ответа) не меняется (1 байт, 7 младших бит это значение кода)

Comment: LC_COLLATE может быть другим. А я в общем говорил, в каких-то локалях всё может быть иначе.

Comment: @0andriy, читайте внимательно. Устанавливая LC_ALL в С мы тем самым устанавливаем LC_COLLATE тоже в С. Соответственно, сортировка будет производиться по числовым кодам байт текста (т.е. в порядке кодов ascii). Когда у вас установлена, локализация, то LC_COLLATE определяет таблицу следования символов заданной кодировки. Скажем для `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` символ `_` предшествует символу `!` (а в ascii, т.е. когда мы выставим LC_COLLATE=C, наоборот)

Comment: Читайте и вы внимательно, независимо LC_COLLATE может быть установлено во что угодно.

Comment: @0andriy, покуда LC_ALL=C установить LC_COLLATE во что-то другое не удастся